# how to calculate mahalanobis distance in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, mahalanobis

What is the most efficient way to calculate the mahalanobis distance: in pytorch?

[image]

Comment: What are x, mu and sigma in your context? Like their shapes, sizes, types etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [SciPy's implementation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.4/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L1035-L1079) of the mahalanobis distance, you would do this in PyTorch. Assuming `u` and `v` are 1D and `cov` is the 2D covariance matrix.

```
def mahalanobis(u, v, cov):
    delta = u - v
    m = torch.dot(delta, torch.matmul(torch.inverse(cov), delta))
    return torch.sqrt(m)
```

Note: `scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis` takes in the *inverse* of the covariance matrix.